# Implementing html, javascript and canvas in a website project

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to create 'a carrier bag' (the rectangle), which has to change its colors by click on a certain button. The customer must be able to add his 'logo' (some text) on the bag (rectangle).

Both codes are working on their own, but when I combine them in one script things mix up.

The code of the rectangle is:

```
var canvas=null;
var context=null;

window.onload = function() {
canvas=document.getElementById("drawing");
context=canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(100, 50, 165, 200);
      context.fillStyle = 'white';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 1;
      context.strokeStyle = 'black';
      context.stroke();
}

</script>
```

This here is the code for adding text that works on its own, but never in combination with the one above:

```
<input type="text" id="text_cnv" size="20" maxlength="12" />

<script>
function clearCanvas(cnv)
{
var ctx=cnv.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.save();
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
ctx.clearRect(0,0,cnv.width,cnv.height);
ctx.restore();
}

function addTextCnv(ctx,text,x,y,maxWidth,lineHeight)
{var words=text.split(' ');
var nr_w=words.length
var addtxt='';
for(var n=0;n<nr_w;n++)
{
var txtLine=addtxt+words[n]+' ';
var metrics=ctx.measureText(txtLine);
var txtWidth=metrics.width;

if(txtWidth>maxWidth&&n>0)
{
ctx.fillText(addtxt,x,y);
addtxt=words[n]+' ';
y+=lineHeight;
}
else addtxt=txtLine;
}

ctx.fillStyle='black';
ctx.font='bold 17px sans-serif';
ctx.fillText(addtxt,x,y);
}
var drawing=document.getElementById('drawing');
var ctx1=drawing.getContext('2d');
var maxWidth=drawing.width-250; //here we change the width of where the letters start
var lineHeight=23;
var x_pos=(drawing.width-maxWidth)/2;
var y_pos=175; //here we change the height of where the letters start
document.getElementById('text_cnv').onkeyup=function(){clearCanvas(drawing);
addTextCnv(ctx1,this.value,x_pos,y_pos,maxWidth,lineHeight);
}
</script>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RasoolGhafari, thanks, but I have to use canvas code, javascript and html, and the one given in the generator in that website is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use http://editor.method.ac/, it's very creative and nice tool to create online editro apps, i'm used from it, it's free and complete. ;)
the main site is: http://method.ac